# jquery select2 case insenstive search by first character

Tags: jquery, search, jquery-select2

I have a dropdown using `'Select2'` as follows:

```
  <option value="1">Banana</option>  
    <option value="2">Apple</option>
    <option value="3">Orange 2</option>       
    <option value="4">Mango</option>
    <option value="5">Pomegranate</option>
```

My implementation is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      //Search method modification
     // Single select example if using params obj or configuration seen above
      var configParamsObj = {
            placeholder: 'Select an option...', // Place holder text to place in the select
            minimumResultsForSearch: 3, // Overrides default of 15 set above
          matcher: function (params, data) {
      // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
      if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
      }

      // `params.term` should be the term that is used for searching
      // `data.text` is the text that is displayed for the data object
      if (data.text.indexOf(params.term) > -1) {
        var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
        modifiedData.text += ' (matched)';

        // You can return modified objects from here
        // This includes matching the `children` how you want in nested data sets
        return modifiedData;
      }


      // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
      return null;
    }
        };


    //Search method modification                            
            //Changepicker disable                  
            $(".selectspy").select2(configParamsObj);
});
```

But when I search letter **a** I need the output which is starting with **a**  which is **Apple**. But I am getting **Banana**.

**I am expecting when I search by 'a'-> 
Apple, Banana, Mango**

I need case insensitive search by first letter.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/4ad7A/274/)

**version : Select2 4.0.0**

Comment: So, you want sort the results?

Comment: @sdespont yes buddy you are right. Sort with case in sensitive search.update my fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to sort returned results : https://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/2317/

Also, update to the last previous version 3.5.4. This function has been renamed as `sorter` in version 4.

```
$('#e1').select2({
    width: '200px',
    sortResults: function (results, container, query) {
        if (query.term) {
            // use the built in javascript sort function
            return results.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a.text.length > b.text.length) {
                    return 1;
                } else if (a.text.length < b.text.length) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            });
        }
        return results;
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

```js
function permute(input, permArr, usedChars) {
  var i, ch;
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
    usedChars.push(ch);
    if (input.length === 0) {
      permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
    }
    permute(input, permArr, usedChars);
    input.splice(i, 0, ch);
    usedChars.pop();
  }
  return permArr;
}


$("#singleSelectExample").select2({
  matcher: function(term, text) {

    if (term.length === 0) return true;
    texts = text.split(" ");

    allCombinations = permute(texts, [], []);

    for (i in allCombinations) {
      if (allCombinations[i].join(" ").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase()) === 0) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
.selectRow {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
}
.select2-container {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body>Single select example
  <div class="selectRow">
    <select id="singleSelectExample">
      <option></option>
      <option value="1">Apple 1</option>
      <option value="2">Orange 2</option>
      <option value="3">Banana</option>
      <option value="4">Mango</option>
      <option value="5">Pomegranate</option>
      <option value="6">Apple 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: it is wrong. Search `Pomegranate` it is showing `Apple then Pomegranate`. It is wrong!! I am expecting something like this http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/4ad7A/276/

Comment: I tried  jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/4ad7A/276  but I am gettin error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`. because my text format is like object Object {selected: true, disabled: false, text: "Click to type name or route number", id: "0", title: ""…}

Comment: @Santhucool here is a working fiddle with your code : https://jsfiddle.net/4ad7A/281/

Comment: that is the same as I have mentioned above. But for using that I got the above errors which I mentioned!

Comment: My dropdown values are not showing! `console.log(text)` it shows all values. Why my values are not showing?? If I give `$('#e1').select2();` then it shows fine!!

Comment: @Santhucool it woks for me, I included your snippet in the answer for your tests

Comment: yah I understand but my case it is not working. please refer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326679/jquery-select2-dropdown-not-working-after-adding-matcher-conditions

Comment: @Santhucool As you have openend another thread, accept answer if you agree that this answer fits this specific question : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work